# Canvas rotation inverse X

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I cannot make [this ray](http://jsfiddle.net/8dfvM/) to follow my mouse cursor.

It's always inverse on X axis.

I think that the problem is with my atan function, but since my trigonometry is fairly low, I have no idea how to fix this one.

This is how I calculate radians:

```
 var dx = target.x - center.x;
 var dy = target.y - center.y;

 var rad = Math.atan2(dx, dy);
```

Comment: `-Math.atan2(dx, dy)` is the solution

Comment: Has the same result as my solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dfvM/7/) - take care for your console to don't blow up), but indeed, a minus sign is easier to type than changing the position of the 2 operands. Changing the position of the operands should provide a 1 byte compression gain when minifying though. `=]`

Comment: `Math.atan2(dy,dx)` is the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dx = center.x - target.x;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dfvM/4/)

---

The fiddle above doesn't work in Firefox as FF doesn't natively support `event.offsetX`/`Y` for mouse events, I assume your normalization code was cut off when making the minimalistic example but I'll leave my normalization code here for future reference:

```
function normOffset(event) {
    if (typeof event.offsetX === 'undefined' || typeof event.offsetY === 'undefined') {
        var targetOffset = $(event.target).offset();
        event.offsetX = event.pageX - targetOffset.left;
        event.offsetY = event.pageY - targetOffset.top;
     }
}
```

Then just pass the jQuery event object to it.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dfvM/5/)

Comment: Well, my actual example is much more different, I just was stuck with that atan and wrote a quick fiddle. This fixed it, though, thanks.

Comment: Yes I thought that'd be case. `=]` Just added my normalization code so my fiddle works in a cross-browser way.